# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Sn[e]')

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting this error on Android:

[image]

I have found that line of code `'Sn[e]'` in 'index.android.bundle' which I have pasted below (ctrl/command + F):

```
for (var An in Sn) xn[An] = Sn[An];
 for (var Dn in wn) Pt(!Sn[Dn], "Event cannot be both direct and bubbling: %s", Dn), xn[Dn] = wn[Dn];
 var kn = {
   eventTypes: En({}, Sn, wn),
   extractEvents: function(e, t, n, o) {
    var r = Sn[e],
     i = wn[e],
     a = Pn.getPooled(r || i, t, n, o);
    if (r) fn.accumulateTwoPhaseDispatches(a);
    else {
     if (!i) return null;
     fn.accumulateDirectDispatches(a)
    }
    return a
   }
  },
  jn = kn,
  On = {
   handleTopLevel: function(e, t, n, o) {
    G(sn.extractEvents(e, t, n, o))
   }
  },
  Mn = On,
  Hn = 1,
  Un = {
   tagsStartAt: Hn,
   tagCount: Hn,
   allocateTag: function() {
    for (; this.reactTagIsNativeTopRootID(Un.tagCount);) Un.tagCount++;
    var e = Un.tagCount;
    return Un.tagCount++, e
   },
   assertRootTag: function(e) {
    It(this.reactTagIsNativeTopRootID(e), "Expect a native root tag, instead got %s", e)
   },
   reactTagIsNativeTopRootID: function(e) {
    return e % 10 == 1
   }
  },
  Fn = Un,
  Wn = null,
  Ln = {
   injectFiberControlledHostComponent: function(e) {
    Wn = e
   }
  },
  Bn = null,
  Yn = null,
  Vn = {
   injection: Ln,
   enqueueStateRestore: function(e) {
    Bn ? Yn ? Yn.push(e) : Yn = [e] : Bn = e
   },
```

Looks like a React piece of code because it has `injectFiberControlledHostComponent` which seems like React Native Fiber. Any idea how I can fix this?

I started the app in android studio and no errors because the app builds and installs fine. I did see this in the android studio gradle console but it's probably not the issue:

> Note:
>   /Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/android/app/src/main/java/com/vepo/MainApplication.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Any update on this? facing the same issue, did u resolve it ? am getting the issue while running the apk generated using ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: Are you using some newer version of `okhttp`?
I had the same issue in a scenario where i was mixing new versions of `okhttp` with not so old versions of react native to solve an `IllegalStateException` by `okio.RealBufferedSink.write`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and fixed by changing `app/build.gradle` as:

`compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`

to

`compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") {
    force = true;
}`

See also this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17840